# Can't call a State in subclass?

Tags: java, enums

I've tried to call this State I made in my main class and then call it in a subclass, and it works for one subclass but not for the other. My main class is called MonGame, the subclasses using the States are Keying and MouseInput. I put the keying functions in the Keying class and the mouse listener functions inside of MouseInput, respectively. So in MonGame (my main class) here's what I declared:

```
public static enum STATE{
        MENU, BATTLE, FEED, PET, AGE
    }

    public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;
```

And in MouseInput (which works fine) I put this:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
int mx = e.getX();
int my = e.getY();

//battleMenu
if (mx >= 190 && mx <= 250){
    if (my >= 290 && my <= 310){
        MonGame.State = MonGame.STATE.BATTLE;
    }
}
//feedMenu
if (mx >=320 && mx <= 360){
    if (my >= 290 && my <= 310){
        MonGame.State = MonGame.STATE.FEED;
    }
}
//petMenu
if (mx >= 200 && mx <= 240){
    if (my >= 320 && my <= 340){
        MonGame.State = MonGame.STATE.PET;
    }
}
//ageMenu
if (mx >= 325 && mx <= 345){
    if (my >= 320 && my <= 340){
        MonGame.State = MonGame.STATE.AGE;
    }
}
```

}

Here's the issue. In the Keying class, I call this:

```
public void Battle(){
    if (State == STATE.BATTLE){

    }
}
```

But it returns an error for

```
(State)
```

in the if statement.

I've tried placing the enum and STATE values into the Keying class, and then get an error in the MouseInput class. Switching them up doesn't work, so how can I get the enum and State values into both subclasses? I've even tried importing all of my main class.

Comment: If you're seeing an error, it makes sense to post the error message, no? You appear to be trying to reference an undeclared variable in Battle, but that's just a guess. A bigger question though would be why would your mouse and your key control classes subclass the main class? This looks like possible misuse of inheritance.

Comment: My apologies. The error is "State cannot be resolved to a variable". So I would assume you are right, but I know next to nothing about this stuff. I thought that State would be inherited by the Keying class because I declared it in the main class? It works for MouseInput.

Comment: Again, the bigger problem is that it is highly likely that your key control and mouse control classes should **not** subclass from the main class. Again this looks to be a gross mis-use of inheritance.

Comment: If you were to see the whole package you would probably be disgusted, lol. I am just learning off of watching other people, taking a look at what other's did, and asking questions off here :/ Thank you, though! :) I'll try to get everything in order package-wise before I go forward.

Comment: The more important things is inheritance should only be used when there is a valid "is-a" relationship going on. A dog **is a** carnivore which **is an** animal. If this relationship does not exist, then inheritance should not be used. A Key controller class does not fulfill this relationship, and if you try to force it into this relationship, your program will likely break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Battle(){
    if (MonGame.State == STATE.BATTLE){
    }
}
```

You were missing the `MonGame.` prefix from State.

Comment: Wow. Well that cleared up the error, lol. I feel very dumb now :$

Comment: All of us make these mistakes. Accept the answer! (:

Comment: @Codereaper: sigh, sure, ignore my comments, but I fear that you'll regret doing so. This answer solves your question, but does not address what is likely a large problem with your program's structure.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well to be fair, I did reply :/ took me a while longer. Is there a page on Oracle where I can figure out about Inheritance and how to structure my classes, and what kind of classes should be subclassed?

Comment: @Codereaper: [Oracle Tutorial on OOPs Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/). I'd recommend that you get several good books on Object Oriented Design.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay thank you :) but would the Display class be an example of the "is-a" relationship? Like the Display is a...which is a...(Sorry for asking so much)

Comment: @Codereaper: likely not, but without code, it's hard to say. Most of my "is-a" relationships derive from interfaces and abstract classes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Interfaces and abstract classes..okay got it. I have a lot of looking up to do :) thank you so much again for tolerating my ignorance. :D